How to disable Acer laptop touch screen through either Ubuntu?
How to disable touch screen on an old Acer laptop Aspire V5 year 2012 through Ubuntu?
It may be possible to disable the touchscreen by disabling the driver.
I want to disable it because the touch screen is crack.
Alternatively, is it possible to disable the touch screen in the BIOS settings?

To close voters: I have edited the question to make it relevant to Ubuntu.
